# Help with a step on this proof of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading [this proof](https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/TMA4190V2018/TMA4190_Lecture21.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0LgmLXqYeaH8Glu1CJT7RXvLYSKqeSFCGUOYc8-gWd21qbdMMZWuks3zw) of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem. I'm trying to understand the part on page 6 where they show that we can get a smooth map $g:\mathbb{R\rightarrow R}$ such that $p(g(t))=f(p(t))$, where $p$ is the covering map $p:\mathbb{R\rightarrow}S^{1}$ such that $t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$.

This is the part I don't follow:

> To make $g$ compatible with $f$ in the above sense, we must have
> $$p(g(t+1))=f(p(t+1))=f(p(t))=p(g(t))\rightarrow p(g(t+1)-g(t))=1$$

This must be something obvious, but why does this implication hold? I can only see that $p(g(t+1))-p(g(t))=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of $p$ as taking $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and producing a point on $S^1$ by starting at the base point $1$ and "going around" by $t$ full rotations. For example, $p(1) = 1$, because going around 1 full rotation will bring us back to the starting point. Likewise, $p(1/2) = -1$, because doing around 1/2 of a full rotation will bring us to the antipode of the starting point.

With this in mind, $p(g(t)) = p(g(t+1))$ tells us that doing $g(t)$ or $g(t+1)$ rotations brings us to the same point on $S^1$. What does that mean about the number $g(t+1) - g(t)$?

Comment: It must be an integer?

Comment: Great! So then $p(g(t+1) - g(t)) = p(\text{some integer})$...

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Thanks!